# Batch how to print DateTime

Tags: batch-file, time

I am having a batch syntax which prints DateTime. Here it is

```
echo mydateTime_%date:~-4,4%_%date:~-7,2%d_%date:~-10,2%m_%time:~0,2%hr-%time:~3,2%min-%time:~6,2%sec
```

I want it to return

```
mydateTime_2015_22d_04m_9hr-41min-06sec
```

But it is returning

```
mydateTime_2015_22d_04m_ 9hr-41min-06sec
```

A space between  `04m_ 9hr`. I dont understand why space is generating ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set "dt=mydateTime_%date:~-4,4%_%date:~-7,2%d_%date:~-10,2%m_%time:~0,2%hr-%time:~3,2%min-%time:~6,2%sec"
echo %dt: =%
```

try this

check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us/19799236#19799236)